# How do I fix my member count in v12 of discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to get the member count but I keep getting an error and I don't know what to do now.

Here is my code:

```
bot.on('ready',() =>{ 
    let myGuild = bot.guilds.fetch('759858083718496266'); // Discord server ID
    let memberCount = myGuild.memberCount;
    let memberCountChannel = channel.messages.cache.get('123456789012345678');; // kanalens ID
    memberCountChannel.setName('Members • ' + memberCount)
    .catch(error => console.log(error));

    console.log(`${bot.user.username} er klar.`) 
//.then(result => console.log(result))
})

bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    let myGuild = bot.guilds.fetch('759858083718496266');
    let memberCount = myGuild.memberCount;
    let memberCountChannel = myGuild.channels.fetch('792504113673142333');
    memberCountChannel.setName('Members • ' + memberCount)
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
});

bot.on('guildMemberRemove', member => {
    let myGuild = bot.guilds.fetch('759858083718496266');
    let memberCount = myGuild.memberCount;
    let memberCountChannel = myGuild.channels.fetch('792504113673142333');
    memberCountChannel.setName('Members ' + memberCount)
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
});
```

I have tried with get instance of fetch and I have tried cache.get but received the same error:

```
let memberCountChannel = myGuild.channels.fetch('792504113673142333'); // kanalens ID
                                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined
        at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lauri\Desktop\QuebecCity\index.js:140:47)
        at Client.emit (node:events:376:20)
        at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (C:\Users\lauri\Desktop\QuebecCity\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:431:17)
        at WebSocketManager.checkShardsReady (C:\Users\lauri\Desktop\QuebecCity\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:415:10)
        at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lauri\Desktop\QuebecCity\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:197:14)
        at WebSocketShard.emit (node:events:376:20)
        at WebSocketShard.checkReady (C:\Users\lauri\Desktop\QuebecCity\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:475:12)
        at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\lauri\Desktop\QuebecCity\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:447:16)
        at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\lauri\Desktop\QuebecCity\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
        at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\lauri\Desktop\QuebecCity\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.fetch()` does not return a value, it returns a `Promise`. You are trying to treat `myGuild` as if it is a `Guild` object, when in reality it is a `Promise` that is "promising" you a `Guild` object. So how do you obtain the `Guild` object? There are two methods: Promises have a `.then(value => {})` function which you could use, or you could use the simpler `async/await` method.

So here's how that would look in your `ready` event:

```
bot.on("ready", async () => {

    let myGuild = await bot.guilds.fetch('759858083718496266'); // Discord server ID
    let memberCount = myGuild.memberCount;
    let memberCountChannel = await myGuild.channels.fetch('123456789012345678');

    //rest of your code

});
```

Simply add `async` before your function declaration, and add `await` before each `.fetch()`. You need to do this in each of your event handlers; the above is only an example in your `ready` event handler.